# I cannot get TinyWall to add Skype to my exceptions

Tags: windows

I've installed a personal firewall called Tinywall. 2.1.6 and I can't seem to add skype to the exceptions in such a way that it will go through the firewall.

It's application executable has been added to the exception list. I've tried adding it by window, adding all related process, and adding by file and so long as the tinywall is enabled Skype just can't go through and connect.

Am I missing something?

Other Info:
Windows 7 640bit

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already whitelisted the exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe in my case), here are some stuff you can try:

1. RightClick on TinyWall tray icon,

   - choose "Manage",
   - select the "application exceptions" tab,
   - click the "Detect" button. The build i tried will automatically detect Skype and whitelist it.
   - If that still doesn't work, you can try either 2A or 2B below:
2. A. Easier alternative, but only do this if you're sure your system is clean.

   - Quit Skype (rightclick on tray icon, "Quit")
   - RightClick on TinyWall tray icon, choose "change mode", "autolearn".
   - Start Skype, login, etc, make sure it's working with an actual call
   - Restore TinyWall to the normal mode. "change mode"->"normal protection".
3. B. Slightly more work for you, but safer.

   - Quit Skype (rightclick on tray icon, "Quit")
   - Make sure TinyWall is operating on "normal protection" mode
   - Start Skype, login, etc
   - RightClick on TinyWall tray icon, "show connections"
   - check the "Show Blocked Apps (in last 2 mins) checkbox
   - sort by the last column, try to find any "Blocked" entries related to skype
   - right click on each item and select "unblock"

Good Luck.